# Asyncio create_task not working in a while loop. does not wait even after using await asyncio.sleep

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to run two functions to test out the feasibility of asyncio. Below is the code for it:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def test_function(value: list, remove_val: str):
    t_end = time.time() + 60
    while time.time() <t_end:
        task = asyncio.create_task(other_function(value, remove_val))
        print("process started")
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        print(f"{t_end - time.time()} seconds left")
        print("Two second passed")
        
    
async def other_function(value: list, remove_val: str):
    t_end = time.time() + 60
    arrayList = value
    while time.time() <t_end:
        if remove_val in arrayList:
            to_remove = arrayList.remove(remove_val)
        print(f"Value {remove_val} removed! array now is {arrayList}!")
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
        print(f"{t_end - time.time()} seconds for other_function left")
        arrayList.append(remove_val)
        print(f"Value {remove_val} added! array now is {arrayList}!")
    
arr= ["joe", "cody", "sam"]
x = other_function(arr, "sam")

y =test_function(arr, "sam")

asyncio.run(y)
```

For this code I am getting the following output:

```
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
55.99424505233765 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
51.98817753791809 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
47.98421788215637 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
43.97970724105835 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
39.99498963356018 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
39.97833061218262 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
39.99493765830994 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
35.97775459289551 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
39.9962203502655 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
31.977003574371338 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
39.9944372177124 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
27.972174406051636 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
39.99572777748108 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
23.970929861068726 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
19.990561962127686 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
39.999760150909424 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
19.968263864517212 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
19.991163730621338 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
39.999332904815674 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
15.966708183288574 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
19.99224877357483 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
39.998931646347046 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
11.965555191040039 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
19.98317241668701 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
39.99503564834595 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
7.964901685714722 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
19.99171495437622 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
39.99918723106384 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
3.963726758956909 seconds left
Two second passed
process started
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody']!
-0.014249563217163086 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
19.998854160308838 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
39.99875593185425 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam', 'sam']!
Value sam removed! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
-0.036725759506225586 seconds left
Two second passed>
```

After the first 20 seconds I keep getting the log:

```
39.99493765830994 seconds for other_function left
Value sam added! array now is ['joe', 'cody', 'sam']!
```

Whereas the code I want should be showing that every 20 seconds but it shows after every 4 seconds with the other logs.

Comment: What on earth is this code supposed to be doing?  Every four seconds, you start another task whose job it is to delete and add an element back every twenty seconds.  It's unclear what the expected output is supposed to be.

Comment: The expected output is just as you said, to delete and add the element back in every twenty seconds. But after the first time, it deletes and adds the element back in every 4 seconds

Comment: But that's not what your code is doing.  It's creating 15 tasks, and each of those tasks is deleting and adding every 20 seconds.